# how to convert a list into an avl tree

Tags: java, list, interface, avl-tree

I need to change my list interface into a `avl-tree`. I know how a AVL tree works, but still don't get, how to save data in the structure.

Is it neccessary to still keep the ID of my old list items and just link them to the AVL tree? 
I am writing a small rpg, where the quests and events are saved in two lists and got different IDs.

This is how I get my items from my list:

```
public Item getItem(int i) {
  if (i < 0 || i >= length()) {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.format("%d / %d", i, length()));
  }
  if (i <= 0) {
    return firstItem();
  } return next.getItem(--i);
}
```

Comment: Some code that shows what you mean by "ID" would be helpful, as Java lists don't actually have IDs.

Comment: public Item getItem(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i >= length()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(String.format("%d / %d", i, length()));
        }
        if (i <= 0) {
            return firstItem();
        }
        return next.getItem(--i);
    } 
this is how i get my items from my list

Comment: Please do not put code in comments. Comments are intended for short explanations and questions. Add the code to your original question by editing it. Also, that code does not explain the matter of the ID. You should probably show actual classes and explain what an ID is. Overly terse questions mean we won't be able to understand your problem and help you.